# Javascript : difficulties when making a hidden element visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have some problems with css manipulation with jQuery.
Here is what I need to do. 
I have these three picture. Each are a representation of a person.

[image: 1st picture]

When we click on one of those, this div appears:

[image: 2nd picture]

The problem is when I close it, the website should become as in the first picture, but the 3 picture don't reappear with $("class").css("visibility", "visible").
I don't know why.

The code (there is some PHP, it's done with Wordpress) :
Here is the code for the first picture (I will keep it short, it's not relevant) :

```
 <div class="team-member" style="position:relative; visibility:visible; z-index:-200;"data-style="'.$team_memeber_style.'">
 <img class="img_avocat" alt="'.$name.'" src="' . $image_url .'" title="' . $name . '" /></div>
```

Here is the code for the second picture :

```
$html .= '<div class="team-member-container" style="position:relative;z-index:-200">';
$html .= '<div class="avocat_container ' .$i. '"  height="400px" style="width:1250px; height:442px;border:2px solid black;z-index:200;position:absolute;top:-5%;">
<div style="width:400px; display:inline; position:relative; z-index:200" class="photo_container"><img class="img_avocat_cont" style="display:inline; padding-top:23px" width="400px" height="200px" alt="'.$name.'" src="' . $image_url .'" title="' . $name . '" /></div>
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;z-index:200; margin-left: 50px;position:relative;padding-top:23px;" class="container_description">
<h3 style="display:block;z-index:200; color:#f5a982;position:relative;">' . $name . '</h3>
<p style="display:block;z-index:200;position:relative;">' . $job_position . '</p>
<p style="display:block;z-index:200;position:relative;">DESCRIPTION</p>
<h4 style="display:block;z-index:200; color:#f18c58;position:relative;">FORMATION</h4>
<h4 style="display:block;z-index:200; color:#f18c58;position:relative;">Expertise</h4>
</div>
<div style="display:inline;" class="avocat_close"><img style="display:inline;float: right;padding-top: 20px; padding-right:20px;" src="http://scmlibravocats.lagencecocoa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/croix_fermeture.png" /></div>
<div style="display:inline; margin-left:28%;" class="avocat_mail"><img style="display:inline;padding-right:10px;"src="http://scmlibravocats.lagencecocoa.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/mail.png" />Envoyer un message</div>
```

';

```
$html .= '<div class="testo team-member" style="position:relative; visibility:visible; z-index:-200;"data-style="'.$team_memeber_style.'">';
```

The Jquery code :

```
$(".avocat_container").hide();
var on = 0;
$(".team-member-container").click(function () {
    if (on == 0) {
        $(this).find(".avocat_container").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".team-member").css("visibility", "hidden");
        on = 1;
    }
});
$(".photo_container").click(function() {

    $(".avocat_container").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".avocat_container").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".testo").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".team-member").style.visibility = "visible";
    on = 0;
});
});
```

Comment: Don't change visibility, just change z-index ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use min-height for this, and you'd also get a nice slide-down transition. Basic idea is to set your 2nd div to min-height:0;, then in JQuery use a click event on the other div to increase min-height. If you keep the z-index of the 2nd div higher than the first, it will appear overtop of it. To close it, attach a click event that resets min-height:0;. Add transition:min-height .4s ease; to your 2nd div and you've got a nice little effect!

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you get elements by '$', it will return a jQuery object (an array-like object) even if there is only one element compatible with the condition, you can use `console.log($(".team-member"))` to see what you have.

In this case, just modify

`$(".team-member").style.visibility = "visible";` 
to
`$(".team-member").css("visibility", "visible");` 
or
`$(".team-member")[0].style.visibility = "visible";`